# How to use wsdl2java 3.3.X version of Apache cxf java 11 using command line

Tags: java, wsdl2java

We were using Java 8 with apache 2.7.0 to convert wsdl to java and it was working fine. Now we want to upgrade to java 11 then getting error message.

How to use wsdl2java Apache cxf 3.3.X version with java 11 using command line.

### Steps tried.

Apache 3.3.0 or Apache 3.3.1 or Apache 3.3.2

When trying to convert using below command

`wsdl2java -client -autoNameResolution C:\SAMPLE.wsdl`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.JAXWSContainer.isJaxws22(JAXWSContainer.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.JAXWSContainer.getServiceTarget(JAXWSContainer.java:61)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.JAXWSContainer.validate(JAXWSContainer.java:68)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:172)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:412)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:105)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.main(WSDLToJava.java:185)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.Service
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 10 more
```

Also tried adding external jar file to CFX lib folder.

```xml
<!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
    
<!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or try this also

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Java Version**

```
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.16+8 (build 11.0.16+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.16+8 (build 11.0.16+8, mixed mode)
```

It didn't work with command line, instead I tried with cxf-codegen-plugin in pom.xml

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>src/main/resources/GIMA2Java.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <faultSerialVersionUID>1</faultSerialVersionUID>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Removed 
1. -Djava.endorsed.dirs="${cxf_home}/lib/endorsed 
2. set TOOLS_JAR=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;      

Got below error but build path has jaxb-runtime-2.3.2 jar files.

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/Service
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.JAXWSContainer.isJaxws22(JAXWSContainer.java:64)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: will not add text image next time.

Comment: You can still edit this one...

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of Apache CFX 3.3.x not contain all required libraries.

**NOTE:** These versions are archived and not supported by Apache. I didn't compare libraries for all versions. Probably some other libraries reuqired for these versions.

#### Missing libraries in Apache CXF 3.3.0

- javax.xml.soap-api.1.4.0
- jakarta.xml.ws-api.2.3.3

#### Missing libraries in Apache CXF 3.3.2

- jakarta.xml.ws-api.2.3.3

The latest version of Apache CXF on `javax.*` namespace is `3.5.5`.

### Command line

Upgrade CXF version to `3.5.5` is strongly recommended.
If it isn't possible, then download mentioned jars under `./lib` folder.

### Maven usage

Upgrade `cxf-codegen-plugin` to `3.3.5`

Additionally add this dependency to `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jakarta.xml.ws-api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Choosing a proper `${jakarta.xml.ws-api.version}` of this dependency is important due to breaking changes about namespace (package).

1. for `javax.*` namespace use `2.3.3` (based on the stacktrace this is the right choice in this case)
2. for `jakarta.*` namespce use `3.x` or `4.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for input, great help. From command line got below message
C:\apache-cxf-3.3.5\bin>wsdl2java -client -autoNameResolution C:\HelloWorld.wsdl
'f' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  but it works fine Mavan

Comment: That's a kind of Windows issue. Fortunately, I haven't use Windows. Try to enclose wsdl parh with quotation marks.

Comment: Will it cause any issue if use javax.* namespace use 2.3.3 instead of akarta.* namespce use 3.x or 4.0.0.  Application works fine, but observed one case where its failing- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76629729/migration-from-java-8-to-java-11-for-soap-web-service       any suggestion