# Migration from Java 8 to Java 11 - for SOAP web service

Tags: java, soap, jax-rs

We are migrating from Java 8 to Java 11, using SOAP web service so required javax libraries.

So we have include below list of jar file as we don't want to change the package with higher version.

- jakarta.jws-api-2.1.0.jar
- jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar
- javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar
- javax.activation-1.2.0.jar
- jaxws-api-2.1.13.jar

updated to higher version
jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar = jaxb-xjc-2.3.3.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar = jaxb-impl-2.3.3.jar

Application is working fine except below one scenario

1. POST Operation
2. EX: Request XML

For enumeration attributes in schema definition are throwing exception when it request is given with " IN" space.

If Space is not given then it works fine.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
       <EmployeeUpdate>
          <Name>Test</Name>
          <Country> IN</Country>
       </EmployeeUpdate>
    </root>
```

**
Country is enum in XSD

```
 <xs:restriction base='EnumeratedToken'>
      <xs:enumeration value='IN'/>
      <xs:enumeration value='US'/>
  </xs:restriction>
```

Is there any issue with jar added for Java 11 handling compared to Java8.

Comment: Is there any issue with jar file, any help would be appreciated